# Can we use "fangs" for human "canines"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

We say "*some animals have fangs*" and "*humans have canines*".

I feel like "**canine**" is a bit formal

Can we use "**fangs**" for human "**canines**" in everyday English?

For example, is "*my fang hurts*" more common than "*my canine hurts*"?

Comment: Only metaphorically. "My canine tooth", not my canine.

Answer (score 4):

**Fangs** in mammals refer to long, sharp canine teeth.  It would be unusual to refer to a normal person's canine tooth as a fang except in a joking or unkind way.

In general, the medical names for teeth (incisor, canine/cuspid, molar, etc) are used only in medical situations, and otherwise any tooth in your mouth is just called a tooth.  The one exception to this are the central incisors, which are commonly referred to as "front teeth" when we're being specific and molars, which are sometimes called "back teeth."

> A: "Ouch, I got hit in the mouth and now my front tooth is loose!"
> B: "Which one?"
> A: "The top left one."

There are other specific teeth that are mentioned occasionally as well, like "12 year molars" (the 2nd molar) or "wisdom teeth" (3rd molar, usually only discussed when they cause problems or are being removed).

Suppose I were hit in the mouth and my upper left canine hurt.  Unless I were speaking to a medical professional, the conversation about this might be:

> Me: "My tooth really hurts."
> You: "Which one?" 
> Me: 80% chance of simply pointing at the injured tooth and saying, "This one."
> ----20% chance of saying, "My upper left canine."

The only time you might call a normal adult's canines "fangs" would be in a pejorative sense.  A person with particularly prominent, sharp canines, for instance, might have their teeth described as fangs by someone being unkind or trying to insult them.

Another case might be with a small child who is just getting their teeth in.  If you knew the child/family well enough then you could call their canines "fangs" in a joking sense.

> "Oh look, Billy's fangs are coming in."

Finally, as mentioned by adzenith in their answer, vampires (as well as other monstrous humanoids like werewolves or pointy-toothed aliens) definitely have fangs rather than just teeth.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t say “fangs” for humans unless you’re actually talking about vampires. I would just say “my tooth hurts” if I wanted to be less formal. “Canine” is a bit more formal but it’s also the only name for that tooth specifically.

Comment: Fangs is often used as a alang term for human teeth in general.

Answer (score 1):

The colloquial term for canines is "eye teeth".